# std::out_of_range while setting a QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt-creator, std, stdstring, outofrangeexception

In my C++ application, I have to select a file with the QFileDialog class.
Then, I verify that my file name is correct (it has to start by "VG").

My file has this structure : *VGx-xx-xxxx-xxx-xxx.pigs*

After what, I set it in the associate QLineEdit.
But each time I select a good file, it crashes, and I don't understand why.

Here are my different function :

**OPEN THE QFILE DIALOG WINDOW**

```
/** OPEN FILE DIALOG WINDOW  **/
void VGCCC::selectPIGSFile()
{
    QString pigsFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName
    (
        this,
        tr("Select PIGS file"),
        "./../VGCColorConfigurator/Inputs",
        tr("Document files (*.pigs *.igs)"),
        0,
        QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog
    );

    pigsPath = pigsFile;
    if(verifyPIGSFileValidity(pigsPath.toStdString()))
    {
        m_filePathLine->setText("");
        m_filePathLine->setText(pigsPath);
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText("File selected : "+pigsPath+"\n");
    }
    else
    {
        m_filePathLine->setText("Please select a valid PIGS (Format VGx-xx-xxxx-xxx-xxx.pigs)");
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText("Uncorrect PIGS file.\n");
    }
}
```

**VERIFICATION OF THE FILE NAME**

```
/** VERIFY SELECTED PIG FILE **/
bool VGCCC::verifyPIGSFileValidity(std::string pigsPath)
{
    splitPIGSName(pigsPath);
    std::string verification = pigsNameTable[0].erase(2,2);
    std::string headerName = "VG";

    if(!verification.compare(headerName))
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText("PIGS name is correct");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

**SPLIT METHOD**

```
/** SPLIT PIGS NAME INTO TABLE **/
std::string* VGCCC::splitPIGSName(std::string pigsPath)
{
    std::string pigsPathToSplit = pigsPath;
    std::string delimiter = "-";
    size_t position = 0;
    int i=0;
    std::string token;

    while ((position = pigsPathToSplit.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        token = pigsPathToSplit.substr(0, position);
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
        pigsNameTable[i] = token;
        i++;
        pigsPathToSplit.erase(0, position + delimiter.length());
    }
    pigsNameTable[4] = pigsPathToSplit.c_str();
    std::cout << pigsPathToSplit << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How is `pigsNameTable` declared?

Comment: Are you sure it crashs when you select a "good" file? I feel like it will more crash when you select a "bad" file....

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is how I declared my table in my class.h :         'std::string pigsNameTable[5];' and in my class.cpp I just declared it as 'pigsNameTable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool VGCCC::verifyPIGSFileValidity(std::string pigsPath)
{
    splitPIGSName(pigsPath);
    std::string verification = pigsNameTable[0].erase(2,2);
    std::string headerName = "VG";

    if(!verification.compare(headerName))
    {
        m_testTextEdit->insertPlainText("PIGS name is correct");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Is unsafe because:

1- You don't check if `pigsNameTable` has an element at index (if a `vector`?) or key (if a `map`?) `0`

2- You don't check that `pigsNameTable[0]` has more than 2 elements. See [erase documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/):

> pos: Position of the first character to be erased. If this is greater
>   than the string length, it throws out_of_range.

You could simply do:

```
bool VGCCC::verifyPIGSFileValidity(std::string pigsPath)
{
    splitPIGSName(pigsPath);

    if ( /* test is pigsNameTable[0] exists depending on pigsNameTable's type */ )
    {
        return pigsNameTable[0].find( "VG" ) == 0; // return true if pigsNameTable[0] starts with "VG"
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `pigsNameTable` is a `vector` the test can be `!pigsNameTable.empty()`, if it's a `map`, `pigsNameTable.find(0) != pigsNameTable.end()`....

Comment: Thanks it works ! Just to notify that when the condition with "find()" return 1 it's true, and when it returns 4294967295 it's false. ( First, I only do : if(pigsNameTable[0].find("VG")) {do something}, and it was like my condition is always valid. So I have to precise pigsNameTable[0].find("VG") ==1 ! Now it works ^^)

Comment: `find` returns the position of the pattern in the string. If it returns 1, it means the string has an extra character before "VG". If string starts with "VG", `find` will return `0`.

Comment: So, to complete my condition, I can do
`(pigsNameTable[0].find("VG") ==1 || pigsNameTable[0].find("VG") ==0)`
?

Comment: If you accept the file name to be either "VG*" or "?VG*", yes. If you only accept "VG*", no. Check what's in the variable, probably your split function does not split correctly.